# `go test` only prints "open : no such file or directory"

Tags: go

I rewrite a program and just removed a lot of code, by just making it a comment. After doing that and adding some tests, it is impossible to run the program anymore.

when running `go build` it has no errors at all.
But when running `go test` i only become some weird output:

```
$ go test
2020/05/05 19:14:24 open : no such file or directory
exit status 1
FAIL    fwew_lib        0.002s
```

This error occurs, before a single test is even run, so within the test framework itself.

Why is there is no file specified that is not found? Any idea, what caused this error and how to fix it?

This error also occurred on multiple machines with windows and linux. And with go 1.14.2 and go 1.13.7.

To get this error yourself:

- Repo: https://github.com/knoxfighter/fwew/tree/library
- Branch: `library`
- Just download the branch and run `go test`

Comment: The error is coming from the test execution. Please include the relevant code *in the body of your question*.

Comment: Also show the output of `go test -v` which will break down the results test by test.

Comment: `txt.go` has an `init()` function that's calling `SHA1Hash(<empty string>)`, which calls `os.Open()` and then `log.Fatal()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fork is missing this line from the parent

```
texts["dictionary"] = filepath.Join(texts["dataDir"], "dictionary.txt")
```

[link](https://github.com/tirea/fwew/blob/3895e77be687634b576514780eb3e5e1045d4f98/txt.go#L174)

But your fork still has this line which depends on the one mentioned above

```
Version.DictBuild = SHA1Hash(texts["dictionary"])
```

[link](https://github.com/knoxfighter/fwew/blob/library/txt.go#L207)

And so the `SHA1Hash` "fatals" out since you're essentially passing it an empty string.

[link](https://github.com/knoxfighter/fwew/blob/library/lib.go#L235)

Comment: Thnks a lot! Learned, that go has init functions, didnt knew that before :)